# Inner join A on B if B not empty, else A

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Two tables:

```
prefix ( id, value )
---------------------
1  'hello'
2  'good afternoon'
3  'good night'


suffix ( id, value )
---------------------
1  'world'
3  'world'
```

I'd like to get 
**all** from table `prefix` which can be **joined** on table `suffix` via `id`

result should look like:

```
prefix.id  prefix.value   
--------------------------
1          'hello'        
3          'good night'
```

well - quite easy so far...
but if table suffix is **empty** I'd like everything from table `prefix`
**without** subselects/ctes or `if....` and in **one** query fulfilling both conditions!
Is there any trick to get this done by some magic having-clause or tricky something else?

[Just for testcases: SQL-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87bd9/2/0)

Comment: What does "empty at all" mean?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty no, he wants an `INNER JOIN` except if the table B is completely empty. And apparently, he wants this without adding any logic to the query

Comment: @DavidSöderlund "empty at all" was just to underline "empty" ;)

Comment: I guess it's not pussible without subselects, ... Why not using Stored Procedure?

Comment: You need to better justify all of the restrictions - who writes code based on requirements like "I can't use IF, or a subquery, or a CTE..." Why paint yourself into a corner? And do you really intend to NOT send a resultset at all back to the client in that case?

Comment: @BenVanHees why do people think a query inside a stored procedure is different from the same query not inside a stored procedure?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I know it's possible to get the result on probably 1000 different ways in a few seconds - just like using an if..else or a subselect, or a cte. But I'm just **interested** if there is a possibility to get what I'm looking for without those things. Why do I have to clarify why I'm asking? ;) If you're not in line with the restrictions mentioned in the question - nobody forces you to answer! if you've an idea, respecting my restrictions - I'm very interested to read about and learn from it!

Comment: This made me wonder if there is a kind of join that only returns values if the right joining row doesn't exist; a kind of 'anti-join'. I guess it sort of does, but it's called an `if not exists` subquery.

Comment: @bukko there are anti semi-joins. It only returns rows from the left if they aren't represented to the right. Can be written as A left join B ON A.key = b.key WHERE b.key IS NULL.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't think that :) I'm just suggesting a readable solution if that is what Nico is trying to achieve

Comment: SO is for specific programming questions not specific restrictions.   Restrictions don't add value to SO as a knowledge base.  A simple inspection of the join syntax should answer the question.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there *is* a way, but I agree with others that your requirements make no (practical) sense.

Anyway, here you go:

1. Join the `suffix` table twice (each time with a left join). One join is on the `id` column, the other on an always true condition.
2. Group the results on the `prefix` columns you want in the output and at least one non-nullable column of the first instance of `suffix`.
3. In the HAVING clause, put a condition that the first `suffix` column is not null or the number of values of a non-nullable column in the second `suffix` instance is 0. (Obviously, every group will have the same number of rows, i.e. the count will be the same for every `prefix` row.)

This is the query:

```
SELECT prefix.id, prefix.value
FROM prefix
LEFT JOIN suffix ON prefix.id = suffix.id
LEFT JOIN suffix AS test ON 1=1
GROUP BY prefix.id, prefix.value, suffix.id
HAVING suffix.id IS NOT NULL OR COUNT(test.id) = 0;
```

And there's also a demo [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e250b/2).

Comment: Why such complexity? Why not simply SELECT prefix.id, prefix.value
FROM prefix
LEFT JOIN suffix ON prefix.id = suffix.id
WHERE suffix.id is not null OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM suffix);  See also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5fa3a/14

Comment: The requirement was not to have subqueries of any sort, that was the point that I was addressing here. Although the wording in the question was "without subselects/ctes", it turned out from the OP's comment under Tim Schmelter's answer that they didn't want EXISTS subqueries either. I suggested my solution with that notion in mind. I agree that the result is rather ugly, though.

Answer (score 2):

You need an `OR` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
   prefix.id, prefix.value
FROM
   prefix 
WHERE 
   EXISTS(SELECT 1 from suffix WHERE prefix.id=suffix.id)
   OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM suffix)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f17ca/1/0)

Comment: Works to achieve the desired result, but uses subqueries.

Comment: @Nico do you expect someone to re-write the T-SQL language to perform the magic you're after?

Comment: Just let the optimizer sort out what's the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is: no, you can't!

Or if you can: No, you shouldn't.